# Why does pointer arithmetic produce incorrect results?

Tags: c

I am trying to move a pointer forward 4096 bytes at a time like so:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void calculate(void* a)
{
    uintptr_t stride = 4096; 
    uint64_t *buff = (uint64_t*)a;
    for (uintptr_t offset = 0; offset < 20000; offset += stride)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s: stride = 0x%x offset = 0x%x buff = %p offset+buff = %p\n", __func__, stride, offset, buff, offset+buff);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    void* address = 0x7f5b588d1000;

    calculate(address);

    return 0;
}
```

However this is the current output:

```
calculate: stride = 0x1000 offset = 0x0 buff = 0x7f5b588d1000 offset+buff = 0x7f5b588d1000
calculate: stride = 0x1000 offset = 0x1000 buff = 0x7f5b588d1000 offset+buff = 0x7f5b588d9000
```

As you can see it says:

```
0x7f5b588d1000 + 0x1000 = 0x7f5b588d9000
```

Why is this computation wrong? The result should obviously be 0x7f5b588d2000

Comment: Do you *really* want to have to put in `* sizeof(int)` every time you do arithmetic on an `int *`?

Comment: Forgot sizeof() i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is done in units of the pointed-to type.  This means adding `stride` to a pointer of type `uint64_t` moves the pointer up by `stride` elements, not `stride` bytes, so the pointer value increases by `stride * sizeof(uint64_t)`.

You should change the type of `buff` to `uint8_t *` or simply `unsigned char *`.  That will move the address up by the given number of bytes.

```
uint8_t *buff = a;
```

Note also that it's not necessary to cast to or from a `void *`.

Comment: Upvoted. Regarding the void* cast, I'm not at a computer to check, but I believe it's required in either C or C++, I forget which, when compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples the cast is required in C++ which is not relevant for this question.